# How to properly do Context Sharing with GLFW?

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw

What I'm trying to do is make it so that if I replace the window I'm rendering with a new window, which could happen because the user switches screens, or switches from fullscreen to windowed, or for any number of other reasons.

My code so far looks like this:

"Context.h"

```
struct window_deleter {
    void operator()(GLFWwindow * window) const;
};

class context {
    std::unique_ptr<GLFWwindow, window_deleter> window;
public:
    context(int width, int height, const char * s, GLFWmonitor * monitor, GLFWwindow * old_window, bool borderless);
    GLFWwindow * get_window() const;
    void make_current() const;
};
```

"Context.cpp"

```
context::context(int width, int height, const char * s, GLFWmonitor * monitor, GLFWwindow * old_window, bool borderless) {
    if (!glfwInit()) throw std::runtime_error("Unable to Initialize GLFW");
    if (borderless) glfwWindowHint(GLFW_DECORATED, 0);
    else glfwWindowHint(GLFW_DECORATED, 1);
    window.reset(glfwCreateWindow(width, height, s, monitor, old_window));
    if (!window) throw std::runtime_error("Unable to Create Window");
    make_current();
}

GLFWwindow * context::get_window() const {
    return window.get();
}

void context::make_current() const {
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window.get());
}
```

"WindowManager.h"

```
#include "Context.h"
class window_style;
/* window_style is basically a really fancy "enum class", and I don't 
 * believe its implementation or interface are relevant to this project.
 * I'll add it if knowing how it works is super critical.
 */

class window_manager {
    context c_context;
    uint32_t c_width, c_height;
    std::string c_title;
    window_style c_style;
    std::function<bool()> close_test;
    std::function<void()> poll_task;
public:
    static GLFWmonitor * get_monitor(window_style style);
    window_manager(uint32_t width, uint32_t height, std::string const& title, window_style style);
    context & get_context();
    const context & get_context() const;
    bool resize(uint32_t width, uint32_t height, std::string const& title, window_style style);
    std::function<bool()> get_default_close_test();
    void set_close_test(std::function<bool()> const& test);
    std::function<void()> get_default_poll_task();
    void set_poll_task(std::function<void()> const& task);

    void poll_loop();
};
```

"WindowManager.cpp"

```
GLFWmonitor * window_manager::get_monitor(window_style style) {
    if (style.type != window_style::style_type::fullscreen) return nullptr;
    if (!glfwInit()) throw std::runtime_error("Unable to initialize GLFW");
    int count;
    GLFWmonitor ** monitors = glfwGetMonitors(&count);
    if (style.monitor_number >= uint32_t(count)) throw invalid_monitor_exception{};
    return monitors[style.monitor_number];
}

std::function<bool()> window_manager::get_default_close_test() {
    return [&] {return glfwWindowShouldClose(c_context.get_window()) != 0; };
}

window_manager::window_manager(uint32_t width, uint32_t height, std::string const& title, window_style style) :
c_context(int(width), int(height), title.c_str(), get_monitor(style), nullptr, style.type == window_style::style_type::borderless),
    c_width(width), c_height(height), c_title(title), c_style(style), close_test(get_default_close_test()), poll_task(get_default_poll_task()) {
}
context & window_manager::get_context() {
    return c_context;
}
const context & window_manager::get_context() const {
    return c_context;
}

bool window_manager::resize(uint32_t width, uint32_t height, std::string const& title, window_style style) {
    if (width == c_width && height == c_height && title == c_title && style == c_style) return false;
    c_width = width;
    c_height = height;
    c_title = title;
    c_style = style;
    c_context = context(int(width), int(height), title.c_str(), get_monitor(style), get_context().get_window(), style.type == window_style::style_type::borderless);
    return true;
}

void window_manager::set_close_test(std::function<bool()> const& test) {
    close_test = test;
}

std::function<void()> window_manager::get_default_poll_task() {
    return [&] {glfwSwapBuffers(c_context.get_window()); };
}

void window_manager::set_poll_task(std::function<void()> const& task) {
    poll_task = task;
}

void window_manager::poll_loop() {
    while (!close_test()) {
        glfwPollEvents();
        poll_task();
    }
}
```

"Main.cpp"

```
int main() {
    try {
        glfwInit();
        const GLFWvidmode * vid_mode = glfwGetVideoMode(glfwGetPrimaryMonitor());
        gl_backend::window_manager window(vid_mode->width, vid_mode->height, "First test of the window manager", gl_backend::window_style::fullscreen(0));
        glfwSetKeyCallback(window.get_context().get_window(), [](GLFWwindow * window, int, int, int, int) {glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, 1); });
        glbinding::Binding::initialize();
        //Anything with a "glresource" prefix is basically just a std::shared_ptr<GLuint> 
        //with some extra deletion code added.
        glresource::vertex_array vao;
        glresource::buffer square;
        float data[] = {
            -.5f, -.5f,
            .5f, -.5f,
            .5f, .5f,
            -.5f, .5f
        };
        gl::glBindVertexArray(*vao);
        gl::glBindBuffer(gl::GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, *square);
        gl::glBufferData(gl::GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(data), data, gl::GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        gl::glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        gl::glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, gl::GL_FLOAT, false, 2 * sizeof(float), nullptr);

        std::string vert_src =
            "#version 430\n"
            "layout(location = 0) in vec2 vertices;"
            "void main() {"
            "gl_Position = vec4(vertices, 0, 1);"
            "}";

        std::string frag_src =
            "#version 430\n"
            "uniform vec4 square_color;"
            "out vec4 fragment_color;"
            "void main() {"
            "fragment_color = square_color;"
            "}";
        glresource::shader vert(gl::GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vert_src);
        glresource::shader frag(gl::GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, frag_src);
        glresource::program program({ vert, frag });
        window.set_poll_task([&] {
            gl::glUseProgram(*program);
            gl::glBindVertexArray(*vao);
            glm::vec4 color{ (glm::sin(float(glfwGetTime())) + 1) / 2, 0.f, 0.5f, 1.f };
            gl::glUniform4fv(gl::glGetUniformLocation(*program, "square_color"), 1, glm::value_ptr(color));
            gl::glDrawArrays(gl::GL_QUADS, 0, 4);
            glfwSwapBuffers(window.get_context().get_window());
        });
        window.poll_loop();
        window.resize(vid_mode->width, vid_mode->height, "Second test of the window manager", gl_backend::window_style::fullscreen(1));
        glfwSetKeyCallback(window.get_context().get_window(), [](GLFWwindow * window, int, int, int, int) {glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, 1); });
        window.poll_loop();
    }
    catch (std::exception const& e) {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
        std::ofstream error_log("error.log");
        error_log << e.what() << std::endl;
        system("pause");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

So the current version of the code is **supposed to do the following**:

1. Display a fullscreen window on the primary monitor
2. On this monitor, display a "square" (rectangle, really....) that over time transitions between magenta and blue, while the background transitions between magenta and a green-ish color.
3. When the user presses a key, create a new fullscreen window on the second monitor using the first window's context to feed into GLFW's window creation, and destroy the original window (in that order)
4. Display the same rectangle on this second window
5. Continue to transition the background periodically
6. When the user presses a key again, destroy the second window and exit the program.

Of these steps, step 4 doesn't work at all, and step 3 partially works: the window does get created, but it doesn't display by default, and the user has to call it up via the taskbar. All the other steps work as expected, including the transitioning background on both windows.

So my assumption is that something is going wrong with respect to the object sharing between contexts; specifically, it doesn't appear that the second context I'm creating is receiving the objects created by the first context. Is there an obvious logic error I'm making? Should I be doing something else to ensure that context sharing works as intended? Is it possible that there's just a bug in GLFW?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> So my assumption is that something is going wrong with respect to the object sharing between contexts; specifically, it doesn't appear that the second context I'm creating is receiving the objects created by the first context. Is there an obvious logic error I'm making?

Yes, your premise is just wrong. Shared OpenGL context will not share the whole state, just the "big" objects which actually hold user-specific data (like VBOs, textures, shaders and programs, renderbuffers and so on), and not the ones which only reference them - state containers like VAOs, FBOs and so on are never shared.

> Should I be doing something else to ensure that context sharing works as intended?

Well, if you really want to go that route, you have to re-build all those state containers, and also restore the global state (all those `glEnable`s, the depth buffer setting, blending state, tons of other things) of your original context.

However, I find your whole concept doubtful here. You do not need to destroy a window when going from fullscreen to windowed, or to a different monitor on the same GPU, and GLFW directly supports that via [glfwSetWindowMonitor()](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/group__window.html#ga81c76c418af80a1cce7055bccb0ae0a7).

And even if you *do* re-create a window, this does not imply that you have to re-create the GL context. There might be some restrictions imposed by GLFWs API in that regard, but the underlying concepts are separate. You basically can make the old context current in the new window, and are just done with it. GLFW just inseperably links Window and Context together, which is kind of an unfortunate abstraction.

However, the only scenario I could imagine where re-creating the window would be necessary is something where different screens are driven be different GPUs - but GL context sharing won't work across different GL implementations, so even in that scenario, you would have to rebuild the whole context state.

Comment: Is there a comprehensive forum or blog post which discusses exactly what gets shared and what doesn't? I tried reading the [OpenGL spec](https://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/glspec45.core.pdf)(Chapter 5) to figure it out, but it's a little too arcane for me.

I'm going to work on rewriting my code so that it doesn't have to destroy the window, but the question is going to remain relevant, since my next step is to work on getting multiple windows to render at the same time using the same objects, which means I'm not going to be able to escape the bugbears of context sharing.

Comment: Apart from the spec, I don't know of any good descriptions. Note that you don't necessarily need multiple contexts for multiple windows, you could also use one window after the other with the same context, and there are some newer extensions which make such context switching less heavy (although it is still not clear if it would be worth it).

Comment: Alright. I'll spend more time staring at the spec. In the meantime, rewriting this code to use the `glfwSetWindowMonitor` and other similar functions resolved my issues, so I'll accept this answer.